# I have a string with counts and alphabets in ordered manner i have to print the alphabets according to their count

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, run-length-encoding

```js
var input = `2
6
z2k1o2
6
m2v1p2`

var newInput = input.split("\n")
//console.log(newInput.length)
var input_arr = input.trim().split("\n")
var n = Number(input_arr[0])
//console.log(input_arr)

for (var i = 1; i < input_arr.length; i = i + 2) {
  var length = Number(input_arr[i])
  var string = input_arr[i + 1].trim()

}
//console.log(string)

var newstring = string
//console.log(newstring)
var alpha = []
var num = []
for (i = 1; i < string.length; i += 2) {
  num.push(string[i])
}
var newnum = num.map(Number)
//console.log(newnum)

for (i = 0; i < string.length; i += 2) {
  alpha.push(string[i])
}
var newalpha = (alpha)
//console.log(newalpha)
var answer = []
for (i = 0; i < newnum.length; i++) {

  for (j = 0; j < newnum[i]; j++) {
    answer.push(newalpha[i])
  }
}

console.log(answer.join(""))
```

Here I'm getting only one output can you please explain why And do you like share any other approach for this problem.

This is the input z2k1o2  and the output should be `zzkoo`
The input will follow this patter of alphabets ans counts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this with a regular expression that captures pairs of (character, number) and uses the function-replacement mode of `.replace()` to generate the replacement string.

```
> "a2b1c2".replace(/([a-z])([0-9]+)/ig, (_, a, b) => a.repeat(+b))
"aabcc"
```

```
>"pos2es2".replace(/([a-z])([0-9]+)/ig, (_, a, b) => a.repeat(+b))
"possess"
```

Comment: no need for `+`, js handles type conversion for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's where you're running into your error:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < input_arr.length; i = i + 2) {
  var length = Number(input_arr[i])
  var string = input_arr[i + 1].trim()

}
```

You're going through the entire input array and saving each of the lengths and strings, but you're overwriting the length and the string each time you read it - only the last length and last string are saved, and so only the last length and last string are processed / printed.